# Actionscript metro app development

Tags: flash, windows-8, actionscript, windows-phone, microsoft-metro

Maybe it's not a good question, but I'm studying actionscript to employ wireframes.

So, is it possible to export windows 8 metro app and windows phone with adobe flash pro?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

No it's possible to export apps to or from Adobe Flash for either of the platforms.

Flash however is supported in the browser on both Windows 8 and RT, but not Windows Phone.

Source: [Adobe Dev. Roadmap](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html)